# tiny mce changes text area width with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, browser, tinymce

I am using Tiny MCE and twitterbootstrap in a form.

Tiny MCE changes the normal width of the text element. Any idea how do I fix it. I dont want to hardcode the width since its a reponsive design.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
.control-group
  %label.control-label  Location
  .controls
    .input-prepend
      %input#location.input.span6{:name => "job[location]", :placeholder => "Location", :type => "text"}/
.control-group
  %label.control-label  Description
  .controls
    .input-prepend
      %textarea#message.input.span6{:name => "job[desc]", :rows => "10", :placeholder => "Paste Job Description. Formatting would be preserved"}
```

This is the JS I use:

```
:javascript
  tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
```

I am attaching the 2 views with and without tinymce:
[image: without tiny mce]

[image: with tiny-mce]

Answer (score 0):

Tiny MCE hides the textarea and adds a `div` so class `span6` to the textarea won't affect the div.

You can add a parent `div` to the textarea and give class `span6` to it.

Something like this

```
.control-group
  %label.control-label  Description
  .controls
    .input-prepend
      .row
        .span6
           %textarea#message.input.span6{:name => "job[desc]", :rows => "10", :placeholder => "Paste Job Description. Formatting would be preserved"}
```